# Capture arguments inside functions in server.R

Tags: r, shiny

Below is sample of the server.R file from R shiny application. So wanted to check if we can show that 
`output$plot` is a function that has `input$dist`, `dist`, `n`, `input$n`, `hist` inside this function. Is this possible to achieve?

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- input$dist
    n <- input$n

    hist(d(),
         main = paste("r", dist, "(", n, ")", sep = ""),
         col = "#75AADB", border = "white")
  })
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? It's not clear to me. Are you trying to find all the variable names? Do you need to do this at run time?

Comment: Yes. All variable names including input$...... in this case it’s input$dist. Not sure what u mean by runtime. Can you provide both please.  I mean with and without runtime?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick Did you get a chance to look at this? Or do you need anything else from me?

Comment: I still don’t understand from your description what you are trying to do. So I don’t think I can help.

Comment: May I know which part you did not understand. I shall try to reframe it